Failing the client certificate authentication requests in windows server 2022
We have successfully migrated from a Windows 2012 server to a Windows 2022 server and updated the IIS configurations accordingly. The server certificate has been installed on the new 2022 server, and this certificate has also been installed on the SAP systems (source systems). The client certificates from the SAP systems have been imported into the target server and configured within the IIS configuration editor using one-to-one mappings.
However, when test files are sent from the SAP systems to the Windows server, the request reaches the server but fails to authenticate the client certificates, resulting in a 403.16 error.
Note: The client certificates have been properly imported into the Windows server and configured in IIS.
Could you please provide a solution for this issue?
Do you have any insights on why we are encountering the 403.16 error, despite having set the appropriate folder permissions and other configurations? If anyone has faced a similar issue, could you please provide some suggestions and potential solutions? Thank you

Server administration is off topic on a programming site. Besides, people do need to access the server for diagnostics, so your best option is to hire a consultant or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com
